# Подчеркивание ссылки на почтовый адрес

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyWgBJ
Как убрать это синее подчеркивание в почтовом адресе?

```
<p style="text-align: center; margin: 10px 0px">
    </p>
    <div style="background-color:#43536e; padding:0 2% 2% 2%;">

 <span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva; font-size: 14pt; color:#ffffff;">
   <br>
        <span style="font-size: 16pt">Хотите стать нашим партнером и получить доступ к оптовым ценам? Тогда:</span><br>
 <br>
   <div style="display: flex; max-width: 97.5%; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap">
            <div>
<p style=" line-height:35px;">
 Шаг 1:<br>
             Пройдите регистрацию на нашем сайте: <a href="http://smartgroup.ua/registration/" style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: 500;display:inline-block;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;line-height: 35px; " target="_blank"><span style="color: white; border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor">Регистрация</span></a></p>
        </div>
<div>       
<p style=" line-height:35px;">
             Шаг 2: <br>
         Получите подтверждение от нашего менеджера.</p>
 </div>
     </div>
     <div><br>
       <hr style="border: 0; color: #5e697b; background-color: #5e697b; height: 1px"><br>
         За подробной информацией обращаетесь по телефонам:<br>
         (0xx) 000 00 00;&nbsp;&nbsp;(0xx) 000 00 00.&nbsp;<br>
         E-mail:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:kovalmh@mail.ru"><span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva; font-size: 14pt; color: white; border-bottom: 1px solid white">kovalmh@mail.ru</span></a></span>
    </div>
    <p>
    </p>
 <br>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто, используйте свойство `text-decoration:none` для ссылки на email